# Convert MI SCALE 2 data to weight data (UUID: 0x2A9D, Weight Measurement)

Tags: flutter, binary, type-conversion, bluetooth-lowenergy, xiaomi

I am trying to develop a flutter application to convert readings from Xiaomi Scale to readable format in mobile.

I get the following readings:

```
KG      55.05       [34 , 2 , 43 , 178 , 7 , 1 , 1 , 20 , 0 , 22]

KG      55          [34 , 248 , 42 , 178 , 7 , 1 , 1 , 20 , 2 , 13] 

KG      14.3        [34 , 44 , 11 , 178 , 7 , 1 , 1 , 20 , 33 , 19]

KG      22.5        [34 , 158 , 17 , 178 , 7 , 1 , 1 , 20 , 36 , 46]

KG      71.65       [34 , 250 , 55 , 178 , 7 , 1 , 1 , 20 , 39 , 58]

KG      55          [34 , 248 , 42 , 230 , 7 , 12 , 23 , 8 , 12 , 40]

KG      2.8         [98 , 48 , 2 , 230 , 7 , 12 , 23 , 8 , 25 , 8 ]

Lbs     12.14       [35 , 108 , 47 , 230 , 7 , 12 , 23 , 8 , 10 , 57]

Lbs     157.8       [35 , 154 , 61 , 230 , 7 , 12 , 23 , 8 , 17 , 5]

Lbs     6           [99 , 88 , 2 , 230 , 7 , 12 , 23 , 8 , 22 , 51]
```

The first 3 integers represents the measurement, the remaining 7 integers represents the timestamp according to my assumption. The last 7 integers matches with the data found from the characteristic with UUID 0x2A2B (Current Time).

Answer (score 0):

I did not get all of it, but this is where I had to leave it.. Hope to update answer later..

55.05 kg => 34, 2, 43

Convert little endian to hex gives: 0x2b0222.
First 16 bits gives 0x2b02 which is 11010 or 55.05 * 200.
I think the last 8 bits are all flags, and the last bit is Lbs.

For Kgs you get the weight in 1/200th of a kg in the highest 16 bits (little endian).
For Lbs you get the weight in 1/100th of a Lbs in the highest 16 bits.

Check out
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/weight-scale-service-1-0/
as I believe the device may conform to that spec.